# How to receive continuously on UDP port and send message on same port when received

Tags: c#, udp

The case for my problem is: There is a program running locally acting like a server sending data on request. I can call for data on port 4096.

I would like to create client side which would send the message requested by the "server" ("GET_DATA") and then listen for whole response (several chunks). Then, after validating wholeness
of the data (CheckCompleteData method) or some time, send request "GET_DATA" again and keep listening for the response.

My code so far:

```
public class Connector
{
    private static UdpClient udpClient;
    private static List<Byte[]> receivedData;
    readonly Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET_DATA");
    private static IPEndPoint ep;
    public Connector(string address, int port, int bufferSize)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        udpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = bufferSize;
        ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port); 
        udpClient.Connect(ep);
    }

    private void SendDataRequest()
    {
        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
    }

    public List<Byte[]> ReceiveAllData()
    {
        SendDataRequest();

        receivedData = new List<byte[]>();
        
        udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), null);

        return receivedData;
    }


    private static void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        receivedData.Add(udpClient.EndReceive(res, ref ep));
        udpClient.BeginReceive(ReceiveData, null);
    }
}
```

So far I managed to receive all chunks of one message, but I cannot call ReceiveAllData repeatedly, because the client is already disposed.

I have no idea how to secure continuous listening with calling some event when data received.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: So...what's your _question_? Please fix your post so that it includes a [mcve] that shows what you've tried so far to solve your problem, along with a clear explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with. A specification is not a question. The above is a specification, and not even a very good one at that.

Comment: @Tyro it wasn't rude - it was direct; you had zero code in the original question, so: how could anyone possibly comment? With the edit: can you show the *caller* code, because "the client is already disposed" would depend on the caller's interaction - in fact, nothing in the edit shows disposal. Honestly, though, this is a pretty bad way of implementing a server; a `List<byte[]>` seems a very poor choice for a buffer stack - it has terrible threading semantics (yet this is inherently threaded), and no change notification. Question: what framework version are you targeting here? Reason:

Comment: it would be pretty easy to swap that `List<byte[]>` for a `Channel<byte[]>`, with the advantage that a `Channel<T>` is **designed** for concurrency and async; a consumer could easily dequeue from the channel-reader (in fact, you should probably only return the reader to the consumer), leaving the writer able to push things in; discussion: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ - note however, if this is high volume, I'd want to look at buffer recycling instead of all these `byte[]`, but that's a more advanced topic